# Checking if List<T> contains specified integer number

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

I am using `List<T>` array to store all ID's that I have read from my database file.

do lets say I have ID: 5, 8, 15

What I am trying to do is to check if user input matches one of the elements in this array.

How do I do this?

I have tried using Contains or Find, but I cannot manage to make it work.

Bit of the code which doesn't seem to wok. It only shows `Entry ID doesn't exist!` only if I enter a letter (?).

```
    List<int> fetchedEntries = new List<int>();

    else if (!fetchedEntries.Contains(intNumber))
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Entry ID doesn't exist!";
        lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.IndianRed;
        btnDeleteEntry.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: What did you try? What happened?

Comment: Errors mostly. I couldn't even make them work.

Comment: Post a bit of code, contains should work fine.

Comment: Post the code you are using to create the list and add the elements as 'contains' should be working as is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx

Comment: please also elaborate on `cannot manage to make it work`. Error descriptions or something.

Comment: Guys, be patient, we should appreciate even so simple questions, just advice how to make answer better, why downvoting?

Comment: @SLaks: A type, should I include a type in contain statement?

Comment: The code looks fine.  The problem appears to be that `intNumber` really isn't in the `fetchedEntries` value.  Have you looked at the list under the debugger to see what entries it contains?

Comment: @sll: This is being downvoted because there isn't enough detail.  An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would make this a decent question.

Comment: There is no type called `Integer`.

Comment: I personally think that you just need to learn using debugger better. First of all it may happen that you do not even reach this `if clause` because it part of `else` branch for some other check. Check this. Then check what number you actually receive in `intNumber` variable. Check whether your list actually contains it. Check all the types, it may happen that you have list of strings while `intNumber` is integer.

Comment: @JaredPar: I believe I have, but I'll double check.

Comment: @JaredPar: It seems like my data to an array is added correctly. I have only 2 elements, number 2, and 3. Yet if I type 1, or 4 this doesn't pick up the change.

Comment: @Snowbear: You are right! It wont work in else if statement. I must use separate IF statement for this! Sorry for creating a lot of confustion here ~_~

Comment: @HelpNeeder are you forgetting to populate the list?  You're checking for values in a newly-instantiated list, and there aren't going to be any.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `Contains` method

```
List<int> theList = GetListFromDatabase();
if (theList.Contains(theNumber)) {
  // It's in the list
}
```

Your Q said this isn't working for you though.  Could you give some more information?  The above pattern should work just fine

Comment: I do everything pretty much the same except: List<int> fetchedEntries = new List<int>();

Comment: Then, in all likelihood, `GetListFromDatabase()` (or its equivalent) isn't doing what you think it is. Try populating the list manually, just for testing. `fetchedEntries.Add(intNumber);`

Comment: @HelpNeeder have you looked at `fetchedEntries` under the debugger to see what values it contains?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an object which has an ID or just the IDs?

If it's just the ID, `Contains()` should work. Since you said it didn't, post what have you done.

If it's an object with an id property, you can use `Where()`

```
int userInput = 5;
IList<T> myList = getList();

if(myList.Any(x => x.ID == userInput)) {
     // Has an ID
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter: at least point out what is wrong, so I can improve my answer or learn from it

Comment: Probably it was for `Where+Count>0` instead of `Any`. Maybe not, who knows

Comment: Do I need to add a namespace for Any?

Comment: @Snowbear: I had never used Any before (actually, I didn't know what it was for). Thanks

Comment: @HelpNeederg: Yes, System.Linq

Answer (score -1):

```
List<yourobject> sd = new List<yourobject>();
sd.Where(s=>s.id == <inputID>);
```

Comment: This won't compile for a number of reasons